# How to create a HTTPS Ingress of NGINX for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

Hello Kubernetes Experts,

I have ingress setup on my micro k8s and it is working perfectly.
However, It is now in http mode and I want to move it to https mode.

I went through the documentation but that very less or relevant data on adding the certificates.

Does anyone have a sample file that I can use to setup ingress controllers with https in micro k8s?

Comment: https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-and-cert-manager-ssl-setup-c82313703d0d , see if it helps.

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using? This cluster is on your local env or its On-Perm?

Comment: I'm using microk8s --> https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dashboard
It is hosted on AWS EC2 Instance with Ubuntu 18.2

Comment: To clarify. You are using Nginx Ingress on HTTP on your MicroK8s cluster. Did you managed to connect to service using Nginx Ingress (not VMIP:NodePort) from another machine?